# How to export text data/ graph in PDF format on QT

Tags: qt

I want to export my grpah/text data in pdf format using QT code.I have done google for a long tim but didn't get any proper answer.If anybody have any idea then request you to please help me.
Looking for your prompt response.
Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Lekhraj

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use QPrinter and QPainter to print to a PDF just like to any other paint device:

```
QPrinter printer;
...set up printer
printer.setOutputFileName( ... );
printer.setOutputFormat( QPrinter::PdfFormat );
...
QPainter p( &printer );
...draw graphs, text etc.
```

That's still quite low-level though, if you need layouting etc., you should look at third-party libraries like e.g. [KD Reports](http://www.kdab.com/kd-reports).

Comment: Dear Frank,

Thanks for your reply,now i can able to draw my graphicsscene  image on pdf.Coul you please give me more info on exporting table on pdf file.Actually my table is dsplaying with help if tablewidget.so how could i will draw that table on pdf file.

Thanks once again for your response.


Dear Roku,

Thanks for your response.Could you please provide me somae dummy example by which i can export my table data in html format then on pdf file.

Comment: user671112: There's no ready-made function for that. You'll have to write it on your own, or use third-party libraries (see above).

Comment: Dear Frank, Problem has been resolved with help of your post.Thanks a lot for your support.Regards,Lekhraj

Answer (score 1):

Make your output containing graphs and text to a html page. Then load the page with a QWebView and print it to a PDF.

You can make the layout design and testing using a web browser. It's much easier to design a nice layout using html than coding everything by hand. If your data layout is quite consistent, you can make a template html file with keywords and then search and replace the keywords with actual data.